# Static mocking is already registered in the current thread. To create a new mock,

Tags: java, junit, mockito

After I made some change to the class being tested (ConsumerKafkaCardReplacementService), I'm getting a lot of errors like this:

```
ConsumerKafkaCardReplacementServiceTest > processCardReplacementSuccessfulWithCIDCredit FAILED
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
    For com.api.loyalty.event.listener.global.RewardsProductConfigService, static mocking is already registered in the current thread

    To create a new mock, the existing static mock registration must be deregistered
        at com.api.loyalty.event.listener.service.ConsumerKafkaCardReplacementServiceTest.processCardReplacementSuccessfulWithCIDCredit(ConsumerKafkaCardReplacementServiceTest.java:308)
```

For static mocking, every mock are closed at the end of the test method:

```
    service = Mockito.mockStatic(RewardsProductConfigService.class);  <-- (line 308)
    service.when(()->RewardsProductConfigService.queryRewardsProductConfigMap(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(TestUtil.getCSSSCProductDetails()));   
    ...

    service.close();
```

No change was made to RewardsProductConfigService class, queryRewardsProductConfigMap method, TestUtil class, getCSSSCProductDetails method. No change was made to the test classes and test methods as well.

I tried annotating the test class with:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
```

and:

```
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.MethodName.class)
```

The issue still persists.
Any idea why?

Comment: Better to use try with resources, but you need to show a complete, minimal example which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve it:

Try declaring the **MockedStatic** in a Try as follows:

```
try (MockedStatic<DateUtil> mockedStaticDateUtil = mockStatic(DateUtil.class)) {
mockedStaticDateUtil.when(() -> DateUtil.llamadaVigente(Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(true);
ResponseEntity responseEntity = ringController.getLlamada(ID_LLAMADA_CIFRADO);
your code.....
 } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

or try the following:

```
 public Class Test {
        private static CloseableHttpClient httpClientMock;
        private static MockedStatic<HttpClients> httpClientsMockedStatic;
        @BeforeClass
        public static void setUp() throws IOException {
            httpClientMock = mock(CloseableHttpClient.class);
    httpClientsMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(HttpClients.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    httpClientsMockedStatic.when( () -> HttpClients.custom().setRetryHandler.build()).thenReturn(httpClientMock);
    // You can also configure the behavior of above line in whatever test method you would like
}
```

Reference
https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/xpsk5x/how_can_i_resolve_a_static_mocking_is_already/